# Using Automator to change the creation date of a folder in Mojave

Tags: terminal, finder, automator, folders, automation

I work as a freelance designer and I have set up an automator app to generate a standard folder structure so that source files are kept in source folder, output folders are in output folder etc. all within my ongoing jobs folder

I use labels a lot and so I have a template folder set up that has the labels I need and the workflow duplicates the template structure and puts it into my jobs folder. I find it easier to search on labels as I can drill down into the specifics with saved searches

The issue I have is that the creation date is always the same as when I first set up that folder so I can't do "sort by creation date" to organise the files and date added only seems to work sometimes.

I have found the terminal command "SetFile -d" and I understand I should be able to run a shell script to run that command, which works if I do it manually in the terminal

But I'm stuck on the syntax for the shell script so that runs script has the file I am working on and today's date and time

Does anyone have any idea how I might accomplish this?

I was thinking along the lines of a folder action that changes the creation date of the folder once it is added to the folder

Any help gratefully received

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing what you already have in your **Automator** *workflow* the only suggestion I can make is the following *example* **shell script** *code* is how I would set the *creation date*, to the *date/time* of execution (or current *date/time*), on a *target folder* containing the *folders* the *creation date* should be changed for:

```bash
find '/path/to/parent/folder' -type d -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} SetFile -d "$(date -j "+%m/%d/%Y %T")" {}
```

The *example* **shell script** *code* uses the `find` *command* to find all *directories* within `'/path/to/parent/folder'`, passing a *null terminated string* (a list of the *directories* found) to `xargs` and executes `SetFile` with the strings as arguments. Thus changing the *creation date* on the *directories* (*folders*).

Obviously `'/path/to/parent/folder'` will need to be defined, *literally* or *tokenized*, and again without seeing what you already have, I'm not going to waste time guessing, to offer variations on the *example* **shell script** *code*.

Comment: That’s really helpful. Is it possible to perhaps add that to a folder for my jobs folder so that any folder added to it gets time stamped then using this method?

Comment: @user1177943, RE: "Is it possible to perhaps add that to a folder for my jobs folder so that any folder added to it gets time stamped then using this method?" -- Many things are possible! However, the first and last paragraphs of my answer still stands.